# Use PIXI.js to export canvas to an image without RangeError

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, html5-canvas, pixi.js

I'm trying to export the entire canvas as a PNG using PIXI.js in a React app that also uses `react-pixi`. I'm on version 6.5 and trying the following:

```js
// MyComponent.tsx

<button onClick={exportImage} />

// utils.ts
import { useApp } from "@pixi/react";

export const exportImage = () => {
  const app = useApp(); // PIXI.Application
  if (app) {
    app.renderer.plugins.extract.image(app.stage, "image/png", 1.0);
    const createEl = document.createElement("a");
    createEl.href = image.src;
    createEl.download = "my-canvas";
    createEl.click();
    createEl.remove();
  }
}
```

However, no PNG image is created and instead I'm getting this error in the console:

```bash
Uncaught RangeError: Invalid typed array length: 9012016008004
    at new Uint8Array (<anonymous>)
    at Extract2._rawPixels (Extract.ts:220:24)
    at Extract2.canvas (Extract.ts:107:55)
    at Extract2.base64 (Extract.ts:95:21)
    at Extract2.image (Extract.ts:79:26)
```

If I do just `app.renderer.plugins.extract.image()` with no params, I do get a PNG but it's blank.

How can I use `PIXI.Application` to export a PNG with the contents of the canvas when the user clicks a button?

Comment: <button onClick={exportImage()} /> should be <button onClick={exportImage} />

Comment: This is psuedocode, the button part works just fine. The issue is the `RangeError`

Answer (score 0):

After much struggle (and help from a colleague), I got it to work by passing in the viewport and limiting it to `app.screen`. I'll post my code to help future searchers who may run into this:

```js
// MyComponent.tsx

<button onClick={exportImage} />

// utils.ts
import { useApp } from "@pixi/react";

export const exportImage = () => {
  const app = useApp(); // PIXI.Application
  const viewport = new PixiViewport(options);

  const imageThis = app.renderer.generateTexture(viewport, {
    region: app.screen,
    resolution: 2,
  });
  const image: HTMLImageElement = app.renderer.plugins.extract.image(
    imageThis,
    "image/png",
    1.0
  );
  const createEl = document.createElement("a");
  createEl.href = image.src;
  createEl.download = "my-canvas";
  createEl.click();
  createEl.remove();
  imageThis.destroy();
};
```